# Add new values in OnModelCreating

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

Once this method fired, can I set pre-calculated values on Caller Entity.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)  
{  
}
```

For instance,

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LAB_LabOrderMain>().Property("RankId") = getvalue();
```

This always set to null.

Comment: You can use migration. do you tried it?

Comment: This is not about migration Saeed. Whenever Insert fire up in code level, I need to pass those values. (suppose that I already have those columns). Thank you

Comment: sorry I was unable to mention it in the questions.

Comment: I've tried with a generic class, whenever OnModelCreating fire up, save those values in the DB. But it always set to null. Is that incorrect.

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)  
 {
  
            modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()  
                .Property(p => p.RankId)  
                .HasDefaultValue(10);         
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);  
        }

Comment: It sames correct

Comment: add-migration doesn't generate anything when I've something like this.  
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(p=>p.RankId).HasDefaultValue(GetRankId());